British 80s movie or TV show scene where a roomful of men have to fight to the death
In the 80s, I recall watching a British TV show or movie featuring a memorable (opening?) scene. A man - possibly a kingpin or wealthy villain - addresses a group of men, declaring something along the lines of: "I shall drop this handkerchief [or scarf] to the floor, and the moment it lands, you shall all fight to the death until only one remains standing."
A brutal brawl ensues, and I vaguely remember the scene ending with a close-up of a man caught in a headlock, blood trickling from the side of his mouth.
It seemed like the men willingly participated, perhaps as part of a twisted recruitment process for the man's next bodyguard or enforcer. Does this ring a bell for anyone?

Do you remember what sort of accent the man had? Might help narrow things down and prompt search terms if it was, say, East End gangster, aristocratic, Northern Irish...

@user56reinstatemonica8 I have an inkling that the guy may have had a posh accent. It has since occurred to me that it might have been an episode of The Professionals, but I can't confirm this.
